Do you think it is consider it is "low quality" if I cite a cryptographic awesome-list in a journal paper?
I'm writing a paper for first time. I am thinking of citing this list (awesome-mpc) along with some survey papers on the Related Work section. Of course a lot of other related stuff will be mentioned in the Related Work section apart for those. This list have helped me a lot in my research, of course it is not a survey just a public index of common smpc frameworks and this is why I will reference some survey papers along with it. I want to ask if you think it will be kind of "low quality" citation for my paper?
PS1 : The journal is an MDPI journal.
PS2 : IMHO this list is a very good start for a survey paper if anyone is interested.
PS3 : I haven't found any kind of awesome-lists being referenced in publications and this list doesn't have an a CITATION.cff file .

Possibly more suited for a mention / thank you than a citation, but I don't have that much experience so I haven't put that in as an answer :|

The quality of the citation depends largely on the relevance to your paper's contents, rather than on it (not) being a peer-reviewed journal article.  I don't think this is on-topic here (crypto.meta SE).
